# Unable to add all items to list

Tags: python

I have a list of timestamps that need to be formatted and then added to a new list. I have been able to do the formatting, but for some reason only one item gets placed in the new list. The only difference in the timestamps is the milliseconds (although this may not always be true, so when I add them to the new list, only one timestamp shows even though lists can have repeated items.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Here is the list:

```
timestamp_list = ['2023-03-15T08:14:54.920Z', '2023-03-15T08:14:54.921Z', '2023-03-15T08:14:54.919Z', 
                  '2023-03-15T08:14:54.918Z', '2023-03-15T08:14:54.918Z', '2023-03-15T08:14:54.916Z', 
                  '2023-03-15T08:14:54.916Z', '2023-03-15T08:14:54.916Z', '2023-03-15T08:14:54.921Z', '2023-03-15T08:14:54.920Z']
```

Here is the code:

```
formatted_timestamp_list = []
def format_time():
    for timestamp in timestamp_list:
        #Convert datetime to string
        pattern = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
        dt = datetime.strptime(timestamp, pattern)
        new_timestamp = str(dt + timedelta(hours=1))[:-3] + 'Z'
        #Format timestamp to a more readable pattern
        formatted_time = (''.join(letter for letter in new_timestamp if not letter.isalpha()))[:19]
        formatted_time2 = formatted_time[:10] + ' /' + formatted_time[10:]
        formatted_timestamp_list.append(formatted_time2)
        return formatted_timestamp_list
new_formatted_time_list = format_time()
print(new_formatted_time_list)
```

Current Output:

```
['2023-03-15 / 09:14:54']
```

Expected Output:

```
['2023-03-15 / 09:14:54','2023-03-15 / 09:14:54','2023-03-15 / 09:14:54','2023-03-15 / 09:14:54','2023-03-15 / 09:14:54','2023-03-15 / 09:14:54','2023-03-15 / 09:14:54','2023-03-15 / 09:14:54','2023-03-15 / 09:14:54','2023-03-15 / 09:14:54']
```

Comment: Your `return` statement (`return formatted_timestamp_list`) is indented a level too deep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you return inside the for block, try putting the return outside the block:

```py
formatted_timestamp_list = []
def format_time():
    for timestamp in timestamp_list:
        #Convert datetime to string
        pattern = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
        dt = datetime.strptime(timestamp, pattern)
        new_timestamp = str(dt + timedelta(hours=1))[:-3] + 'Z'
        #Format timestamp to a more readable pattern
        formatted_time = (''.join(letter for letter in new_timestamp if not letter.isalpha()))[:19]
        formatted_time2 = formatted_time[:10] + ' /' + formatted_time[10:]
        formatted_timestamp_list.append(formatted_time2)
    return formatted_timestamp_list
new_formatted_time_list = format_time()
print(new_formatted_time_list)
```

In python the blank space matters, and it can mess up your code.

Comment: Thanks. @Axe319 had already given me the answer.

Comment: I didn't see that... well, I tried my best anyway... :)